# PHP database file upload error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, file-upload

i am using following code for uploading image files, when uploading process to path working well, but when file path insert to  database table field i get error

uploader.php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('fileupload4',$db);
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png');
$max_filesize = 10000000;
$upload_path = 'images/'; 
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$extension = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
if(!in_array($extension , $allowed_filetypes)) {
    die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
}
if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) {
    die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
}
if(!is_writable($upload_path)) {
   die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_path.$filename)) {
    echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="'.$upload_path.$filename.'" title="Your File">Here</a>';
} else {
    echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed
}
$sql = "UPDATE students SET image = '".$upload_path."' WHERE id = 'student_id'";
mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
?>
```

this is what i get error when uploading image

```
Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

thanks for any help...

my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
  KEY `image` (`image`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: See this happens whenn you just pick up a code without understanding it, its my code :p am using id, and you are not, so it's showing you this error

Comment: Looks like a Error in your SQL-Syntax... i think you want something like "WHERE student_id = '{valueFromInput}'";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the line

```
$sql = "UPDATE students SET image = '".$upload_path."' WHERE id = 'student_id'";
```

needs to be changed to

```
$sql = "UPDATE students SET image = '".$upload_path."' WHERE student_id = 'student_id'";
```

since you don't have a column named id but you have one named student_id

Comment: i tried this query... now no more error, but still dont store image path my image field, why?

Comment: it looks like the upload path you are storing in the database is just 'images/' and you don't ever create the full path to store in the database.

Comment: will you explain how to crate full path.? because this is first time i tried php file upload function.... have any example.?

Comment: Looking at the code you posted it looks like the full path is being created here `code echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="'.$upload_path.$filename.'" title="Your File">Here</a>'; `

Answer (score 1):

Check your MYSQL table structure, apparently the column `id` does not exist.

Maybe post your SQL table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
  KEY `image` (`image`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Answer (score 1):

As the query you posted here it seems like you are not using `id` column(As I already told you in my comment before), as @saratis told you, so your query should be

```
UPDATE students SET image = '".$upload_path."' WHERE student_id= 'pass your id here';
```

Comment: i had fixed query mistakes, but still my image path didnt store image field... any idea.?